# How to get a list of submodules through github API?

Tags: github, github-api, git-submodules

I'm trying to get a list of submodules of a repository through GitHub API. After reading [Github API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/), I did the following things: In Order to access the submodules of the Jquery, I use the following [link](https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/contents/) to get a list of submodules, however, I cannot see any submodules from it. Could anyone please tell me what field should I use to get a list of submodules of a repository from GitHub API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the list of [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) using [Github GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) with the `submodules` connection property :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "bertrandmartel", name: "javacard-tutorial") {
    submodules(first: 100) {
      nodes {
        name
        path
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try this in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository%28owner%3A%20%22bertrandmartel%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22javacard-tutorial%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20submodules%28first%3A%20100%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Output :

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "submodules": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "name": "oracle_javacard_sdks",
            "path": "oracle_javacard_sdks"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this will give only submodules on default branch's `HEAD`, from [the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/repository/#submodules) :

> Returns a list of all submodules in this repository parsed from the .gitmodules file as of the default branch's HEAD commit.

Note that the [jquery repository](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) doesn't have any git submodules in its default branch's `HEAD` (and I don't see any in its other branches)

Answer (score 1):

If you use v3 REST API you can

1. Get the HEAD commit SHA of the branch.
2. Use the returned commit SHA as the tree_sha to get tree. GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/trees/{tree_sha}
3. Iterate the returned tree object for entry that has mode 160000 (submodule)